# Is the activation form still a valid way to get my API key working on evernote production server?

Tags: evernote

I've had submitted my app key with activation form a week ago. But still, I have no answer.
Does anybody know any communication points to get status of the submission?
I tried devsupport@evernote.com but they are silent as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key has been activated after 10 days left. So, just need to wait.